# how to do math operations without removing "NA" in time series data in mathematica

Tags: date, wolfram-mathematica

I am new to Mathematica and currently working with time series data.

I have the following input data in Mathematica 9.0

```
data = {{{2011, 3, 13}, 10}, {{2011, 3, 14}, "NA"}, {{2011, 3, 15}, 
    20}, {{2011, 3, 16}, 30}, {{2011, 3, 17}, "NA"}};
```

Once, I remove the "NA", the data become

```
data = {{{2011, 3, 13}, 10}, {{2011, 3, 15}, 
    20}, {{2011, 3, 16}, 30}}
```

I want to do the math operation, such as plus, minus, and mean, without removing "NA" (I want to keep the sequence of date).

For example, in case that I want to divide the values with mean of the data,
my output could be

```
data = {{{2011, 3, 13}, 0.5}, {{2011, 3, 14}, "NA"}, {{2011, 3, 15}, 
    1}, {{2011, 3, 16}, 1.5}, {{2011, 3, 17}, "NA"}};
```

Are there any ways that Mathematica can do it? or any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = {{{2011, 3, 13}, 10}, {{2011, 3, 14}, "NA"}, {{2011, 3, 15}, 20}, 
        {{2011, 3, 16}, 30}, {{2011, 3, 17}, "NA"}} /. "NA" -> Undefined;
mean = Mean@Cases[data[[All, 2]], Except[Undefined]];
{#[[1]], #[[2]]/mean} & /@ data
(*
{{{2011, 3, 13}, 1/2}, {{2011, 3, 14}, Undefined}, 
 {{2011, 3, 15},   1}, {{2011, 3, 16}, 3/2}, 
 {{2011, 3, 17}, Undefined}}
*)
```

Comment: Any reason you used `Undefined` rather than either leaving it `"NA"` or using `Missing["NotAvailable"]`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `Undefined / x == Undefined` For all x. I see that as cleaner than `"NA"/x`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize `Undefined` was a System Symbol in v8. +1

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using `Indeterminate` in place of `"NA"`.  When combined with a numeric quantity it evaluates to `Indeterminate`, e.g.:

```
1 + Indeterminate
2 * Indeterminate
```

> ```
> Indeterminate
>
> Indeterminate
> ```

This simplifies [tensor operations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3069/121).  Here using `DivideBy`:

```
data = {{{2011, 3, 13}, 10}, {{2011, 3, 14}, "NA"}, {{2011, 3, 15}, 20},
        {{2011, 3, 16}, 30}, {{2011, 3, 17}, "NA"}};

data = data /. "NA" -> Indeterminate;

data[[All, 2]] /= Mean @ Select[data[[All, 2]], NumericQ];

data
```

> ```
> {{{2011, 3, 13}, 1/2}, {{2011, 3, 14}, Indeterminate},
>  {{2011, 3, 15}, 1}, {{2011, 3, 16}, 3/2}, {{2011, 3, 17}, Indeterminate}}
> ```